# Crystal reports failed to open connection

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, sql-server-express

hey there everyone.
so, have a c# windows form that uses crystal reports and a sql express backend and one crystal report that pulls from a remote sql server 08. when trying to pull from the local database, i get a 'failed to open connection' but the report loads fine from the remote connection.

everything works great on the development machine, it's when testing on a virtual machine it fails. the DB on the virtual was created using a (current)backup of the develoment DB. here's the code for the connection...

```
private void frm_cr_Visit_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Text = "Visit Report - Version:" + Application.ProductVersion;
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
        ReportDocument cryRpt = new ReportDocument();
        cryRpt.Load(@"C:\Data\MRE\crVisitBySubVisitID.rpt");
        cryRpt.SetDatabaseLogon("login", "password", @"localserver\sqlexpress", "DBname");
        cryRpt.SetParameterValue("@VisitID", intVisitID);
        cryRpt.SetParameterValue("@FullName", GlobalVariables.GlobalFullName);
        crv.ReportSource = cryRpt;
        crv.Refresh();
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
    }
```

all other DB functions within the program work. what causes the problem, and how do i fix it?

thanks!
dave k

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found my problem, it had to do with the sql server being set up for only windows authentication, and not that and sql login authentication.

doh!

Answer (score 0):

If every other function works and the db details are the same, check permissions for the user as that is the usual cause of connection problems (supposing authentication returns that error obviously), also check the url as (without further information on server names) assume that "localserver" possibly should be "localhost", obviously if HOSTS file or server name is set so that "localserver" works ignore that.

Comment: thanks for the reply, sorry, forgot to close this. ended up finding my answer with more research...  on the virtual machine i was testing this on, the install of SQL Server 08 express was a silent install and defaulted itself to windows authentication only. the program that access the local db uses a SQL login.